# Error - 'create_function is deprecated'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Our WP Debug is report that 'Function create_function() is deprecated'. Any idea how to rewrite this code to not include create_function ?

```
 self::register_form_init_scripts( $form, $field_values, $ajax );

            if ( apply_filters( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', false ) ) {
                add_action( 'wp_footer', create_function( '', 'GFFormDisplay::footer_init_scripts(' . $form['id'] . ');' ), 20 );
                add_action( 'gform_preview_footer', create_function( '', 'GFFormDisplay::footer_init_scripts(' . $form['id'] . ');' ) );
            }
```

Comment: why not just use a anonymous function and call `GFFormDisplay::footer_init` there? what is the minimum php version you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need to use `create_function` you can instead just use an anonymous function:

```
add_action( 'gform_preview_footer', create_function( '', 'GFFormDisplay::footer_init_scripts(' . $form['id'] . ');' ) );
```

Should be:

```php
add_action( 'gform_preview_footer', function() use ($form){
    GFFormDisplay::footer_init_scripts($form['id']);
});
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php